# Admob - IAB TCF v2.0 errors detected

Tags: android, admob

Recently I implemented consent dialog for users based on https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start

Today I received the next issue in my Admob account:

> IAB TCF v2.0 errors detected. We've detected an issue on your IAB TC
> string on one or more of your sites or apps. These errors may affect
> your ability to serve ads to European users. A detailed report is
> available for you on the EU user consent page.

[image: It]

I pressed "GO TO EU USER CONSENT" button and this was shown:

[image]

Downloaded csv file, here's content:

iab_tcf_errors_12_3_2020.csv

```
Mobile App,Ad unit,Error,Error count,Last detected date
com.*.*,7579454036,1.2,140,12/2/2020
com.*.*,3141515571,1.2,140,12/1/2020
```

Error code 1.2 from https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9999955:

[image]

Consent code in my app (`userConsentSDKSetup` is called in `onCreate` of launch activity):

```
 fun userConsentSDKSetup() {
    val params = ConsentRequestParameters.Builder().build()
    val information = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(activity)
    information.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
        activity,
        params,
        {
            // The consent information state was updated.
            // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
            if (information.isConsentFormAvailable && information.consentStatus == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                activity.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
                    loadUserConsentForm(information)
                }
            }
        },
        { Timber.e("userConsentSDK error ${it.message}") }
    )
}

private fun loadUserConsentForm(information: ConsentInformation) {
    UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
        activity,
        { consentForm ->
            if (information.consentStatus == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                activity.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
                    consentForm.show(activity) { // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                        loadUserConsentForm(information)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ) { Timber.e("userConsentSDK error loadForm ${it.message}") }
}
```

So what is wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Also have this error in AdMob. According to docs, we shouldn't manually modify ad request or smth else to notify about user consent status, so, unfortunately, I think we only can wait for UMP library updates. I've temporary disabled personalized ads, but still have  this error in console after few days

Comment: Temporary solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65560468/1241170